# How to calculate the pass level of an exam? (4 answer options; exactly 1 is correct; no negative points)

Tags: probability, statistics

In a "choose the one best answer" exam (4 answer options and exactly 1 is correct; no negative points) the expected exam result based on random guesses would be 25%. If the test takers are requested to show 50% knowledge (that is not based on randomness) what would be the necessary pass level? I guess it is not 75% (25+50) or 62,5% ((100-25)/2 + 25)? How can I calculate the necessary pass level so that each test taker needs to show 50% knowledge?

Comment: Assume exactly $100$ questions of which the student gets the 1st $50$ right and guesses the next $50$.  $$50 + \left[\frac{50}{4}\right] = 62.5.$$

Comment: if you post this as an answer then I will accept it :-)

Comment: No, I can't do that.  For an explanation, see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) and ask yourself whether mathSE reviewers are going to regard your question as defective.  The point of my comment was not to give you an answer, but to guide your thinking.  In my judgement, this was a borderline case, because you had shown the *suggestion* of effort.  I provided the minimum insight that I could conjure that would still meaningfully guide your thinking.

Comment: Personally, I don't agree with the mathSE protocol.  At the same time, I regard my disagreement as irrelevant.